# Match longest substring with regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have several substrings which I want to search for, let's say: `substrings = ['ABC', 'ABCDE']`. I also have several strings like `'xyzABCxyz', 'xyzABCDExyz'`. My regex pattern provided to `re.search()` is: `'(%s)' % '|'.join(substrings)`. Now, searching for either in `'xyzABCxyz'` works just fine, but in `'xyzABCDExyz'` all I get is `'ABC'`.

My question is: what should I do to make regex not stop at finding the shortest substring? All that comes to my mind is to change the substrings order but I'm looking for something more elegant.

Comment: You could sort substrings array by elements' length and then join the elements. Or you could use lookarounds.

Comment: Just sort the substrings descending by size, then iterate and use `re.search`, stopping with the first match, which would also coincide with the longest substring.  There are also non regex solutions here.

Comment: Not sure it's related to your issue. But do note that the OR in a regex capture group doesn't do things in a greedy way.  F.e. `/(foo|foobar)/` would only match "foo" in "going to the foobar.".  But `/(foobar|foo)/` would match "foobar"

Comment: There wouldn't be a more elegant way to do it. Just desc sort it by length.