# Match longest string in Regex OR in case of common substring

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

In a regex OR, When there are multiple inputs with a common prefix, The regex will match the first input in `Regex OR` instead of longest match.

For example, for the regular expression `regex = (KA|KARNATAKA)` and `input = KARNATAKA` the output will be 2 matches `match1 =KA` and `match2 = KA`.

But what I want is complete longest possible match out of given input in `Regex OR` which is `match1 = KARNATAKA` in my given example.

[Here is the example in a regex client](https://regex101.com/r/ecpo5R/1)

So what I am doing right now is, I am sorting the input in `Regex OR` by length in descending order.

My question is, Can we specify in the regex itself to match the longest possible String? Or is sorting the only way to do it?

[I have already refered this question and I don't see a solution other than sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530789/match-longest-substring-with-regex)

Comment: try this \b(KA|KARNATAKA)\b

Comment: @SHAHAKASH What if he wants to match `KARNA`. Your solution `\b(KA|KARNA)\b` won't work there

Comment: What is the problem that is stopping you from sorting?

Comment: @Jai there's no problem sorting the inputs when the input is very less or it's a one time job. There will be a performance issue when we've huge input and we've to do it again and again dynamically. I just wanted to know if we can let the `Regex engine ` handle this.

Comment: Why not use regex quantifiers _*_ like [this](https://regex101.com/r/ecpo5R/2) ?

Comment: @Rahul Because he does not want to match [`KABLABLABLA`](https://regex101.com/r/ecpo5R/3)

Comment: @Rahul what if someone enters KAAAA? your solution won't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35997376/how-to-order-regular-expression-alternatives-to-get-longest-match/36296918

Comment: @ArunGowda try (KARNATAKA|KA)

Comment: try to use word boundary `\b`, `(\bKA\b|\bKARNATAKA\b)` will work

Answer (score 1):

You can use word boundary (`\b`) to avoid matching prefixes

For the case you mentioned: the following regex will only match `KA` or `KARNATAKA`

```
(\bKA\b|\bKARNATAKA\b)
```

[Try here](https://regex101.com/r/7WTtLx/1)

Comment: What if he wants to match KARNA. Your solution (\bKA\b|\bKARNATAKA\b)  won't work there see in a comment.

Comment: @SHAHAKASH It is *not* supposed to match "KARNA".

Comment: he wants longest match.

Comment: @SHAHAKASH Longest *exact* match.

Comment: if String test="KA KARN" --> then he wants KARN, not KA that's a question if I not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper method for this:

```
public final class PatternHelper {
    public static Pattern compileSortedOr(String regex) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\((.*\\|.*)\\)(.*)").matcher(regex);

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            List<String> conditions = Arrays.asList(matcher.group(2).split("\\|"));
            List<String> sortedConditions = conditions.stream()
                                                      .sorted((c1, c2) -> c2.length() - c1.length())
                                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());

            return Pattern.compile(matcher.group(1) +
                                       "(" +
                                       String.join("|", sortedConditions) +
                                       ")" +
                                       matcher.group(3));
        }

        return Pattern.compile(regex);
    }
}

Matcher matcher = PatternHelper.compileSortedOr("(KA|KARNATAKA)").matcher("KARNATAKA");
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
KARNATAKA
```

P.S. This only works for simple expressions without nested brackets. You would need to tweak if you are expecting much complex expressions.